# Studying the $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ when $p(x)$ is any degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, $p(x)\in F[x]$. If $p(x)=0$, then $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle=F[x]/\langle 0\rangle=\bigl\{\{a\}\mid a\in F[x]\bigr\}$, a set of sets of one element. If $\deg p(x)=0$, then $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle=\{F[x]\}$, a set with one element. Am I correct? And if $\deg p(x)\geq1$, under what circumstances will $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$strictly larger than $F$ (view $F$ as the isomorphic copy in it)?

Comment: No, and no. The first one is isomorphic with $\;F[x]\;$ itsefl, and the second one to $\;F\;$ . About "larger" it can be pretty misleading, but in *any* other case the quotient ring will contain an isomorphic copy of $\;F\;$ , even if this quotient is not a field...or even not an integer domain.

Comment: @DonAntonio For the first question, according to what you said, is my $\bigl\{\{a\}\mid a\in F[x]\bigr\}$ wrong? And for the second, is not $\langle p(x)\rangle=F[x]$ and hence $F[x]/F[x]=\{F[x]\}$?

Comment: I would avoid thinking of quotient objects as sets. While they have an underlying set, this set is not identical to the object itself, which is a set with extra structure (i.e. two binary operations satsfying certain compatibilities).

Comment: @Eric As you wrote it, the set $\;\bigl\{\{a\}\mid a\in F[x]\bigr\}\;$ is a set all of whose elements are sets of the form $\;\{p(x)\}\;,\;\;p(x)\in F[x]\;$ . That you denote polynomial in $\;F[x]\;$ as $\;a\;$ doesn't change this. And $\;F[x]\;$ is the set of all polynomials over $\;F\;$ , **not** a set of all the singletons $\;\{a\}\;$ , when $\;a\;$ is a polynomial. And if $\;\deg f=0\;$ then $\;f(x)=k=\;$ a constant polynomial, $\;k\neq0\;$ ,and thus $\;F[x]/\langle k\rangle\cong F\;$

Comment: @Eric Strictly speaking, you're not wrong. If we want to speak about the underlying set, each element $a \in F[x]$ is the only element in its equivalence class in $F[x]/(0)$.

Comment: @leibnewtz "strictly" speaking he's wrong. Read my comment above. Now, not-strictly speaking he could be right...depending on what **exactly** he meant. And if the OP meant "equivalence classes" ,the usual notation is $\;[a]\;$ , not $\;\{a\}\;$ ...but this could be forgiven... **if** he actually meant that.

Comment: OK, I see that the underlying set shouldn't be mistaken as the structure itself. However I want to check if I'm correctly get the underlying set.

Comment: @DonAntonio An equivalence class *is* a set, it's the set of all elements in $F[x]$ related under an equivalence relation. So set theoretically $F[x]/(0)=\{ \{a\} | a \in F[x] \}$ and $F[x]/c = \{F[x]\}$, where $F[x]$ in the latter is just the underlying set of the ring

Comment: If we want to think set-theoretically here, the right thing to do is to write the field as $(F[x], +, \cdot)$

Comment: @leibnewtz Thanks, I knew that...and that's the reason I wrote "what he **meant**  ...but if he doesn't write *specifically* "equivalence classes in the quotient" then chances are many won't understand.